# How to solve ChunkedJson Errors

Tags: php, json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create login screen with php. But when i click the login button the errors below are occuring.

```
    Future<http.Response> osmLogin() async {
    final response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.17.75/login/login.php"), body: {
      "username": user.text,
      "password": pass.text,
    });

    var datauser = json.decode(response.body);

    if (datauser[0]['level'] == 'admin') {
      print(datauser);
    }

    return response;
  }
```

Error;

[image]

Comment: Can you print response.body before decoding it.

Comment: It prints "success" from my php file. `<?php

$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "osm");

if(!$connect) {
 echo json_encode ("failed");
}

else {
 echo json_encode ("success");
}

?>`

Comment: Why did you tag this with "php"? That's not clear from the question. If you have similar working code in PHP, then please add that to the question as well. Please also extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, put the output of that into the question as *text* so it can be searched. You did search for the error already, right?

Comment: If you're expecting just "success" you don't need to use json.decode since it's just a `String`

Comment: No I'm expecting to recieve the data from db and print them on the screen as username and password if the user has admin level on db.

Comment: Sorry for the tag I couldn't explain clear. But yes I already searched for the error and didn't find anything.

Comment: @Josteve you, actually, need

Comment: @ozgurburakbulut can't you see the **actual** output in the Network tab?

Comment: Yes I can see the username and password there.

Comment: NOT the input but **output**,  what the server **sends back** and what causes your chunked json error. it is called Response